# My simple flask mail app that workes on my local host those not work on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-mail

the app sends emails and works properly when tested locally
below is my configuration

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']= 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']= True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL']= False
app.config['MAIL_DEBUG']= True
app.config['TESTING']=False
app.config['MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']='xxxxxx@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']='xxxxx'
```

this is where i run the actual email function

```
def post(self):
    users = []
    data = USER.parser.parse_args()

    if User.find_by_username(data['username']):
        return {"message": "User with that username already exists."}, 400
    user = User(data['username'],data['password'],data['email'])
    users.append(user)

    message = Message('type in this to verify your email "random" ', sender ="xxxxx.com",recipients =[user.email])
    message.body = "na message be this"
    mail.send(message)
```

i dont know if there is any further required information

Comment: I hope that's not your actual security key...

Comment: Don't use Gmail on Heroku. It's not designed for programmatic use. Use a product that's actually designed for this like SendGrid or Mailgun.

Comment: no its not lol i am not dumb

Comment: please further explain your comment about send grid

Comment: i dont quite understand